# How to display data from DB into a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a form and I have been able to save the details into my database but I want is to show the saved details into my TextView when user comes to the same activity.
Here is the current code for of my Form:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.emailsettings);

      nameTU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_username);
      nameTP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_password);
      nameTO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_to);

      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

      if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         nameTU.setText(extras.getString("username"));  
         nameTP.setText(extras.getString("password"));  
         nameTO.setText(extras.getString("id_to"));  
      }
}
```

What I want is to show the saved data on page load in my text_username, text_password and text_to and all these are TextView.

Thanks.

Comment: where u are retrieve user details from database post relevant code

Comment: I know how to fetch the details from database but i am not sure to post the retrieved data in my textview and thats why i have posted this question. Thats my query for fetching data:
public Cursor getEmailDetails() 
      {
         return database.query("details", new String[] {"username", "password", "id_to"},  null, null, null, "username", "password", "id_to");
      }

Comment: because your code for showing data in TextView's is right that's why i'm saying post relevant code from which you are sending data to detail activity

Comment: @AliAbid You are displaying above field in TextView or EditText?

Comment: Sorry you mean Data From Database to TextView or Data to TextView from DB?

Comment: @AliAbid Then what is your problem?, give clear information.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya I know how to save the data from my Textbox into DB but I dont know how to display the same data again into that box(data from DB) when the user comes to that activity again next time.

Comment: his problem is that he doesn't know how to extract data from a query. you do `cursor.moveToNext()` then do `string text1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumIndex("username"))` where username is the column title

Comment: @AliAbid : no i'm saying you have Form Activity with text_username,text_password . TextView in which u want to show data retrived from DB right?. now you are using `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); ` in your from Activity for receiving bundle. so i'm saving post code from which you are sending this bundle to your form Activity

Comment: @AliAbid Means you don't know how to get data from db?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya I know how to get the data from db but i dont how to pass that data to a EditView or TextView.

Comment: @AliAbid Post you complete java code and what you have tried?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya I using this as a guess but app crashing. I am new so might be missing something.

final TextView dbText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_username);
        String storedData = dbText.getText().toString();
        dbText.setText(storedData);

Comment: @AliAbid But without complete information how can help you?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya I havent got anything else to share as I am hare to get help as to how to show the DB data into an EditView. Thanks